# XML saved by application installed in Program Files: where is it?

Tags: c#, xml, program-files

I've spent the last two hours Googling on this with no results, so…

I am developing an application which uses XML files to save data. These files are supposed to exist in the same directory as the program executable. I use:

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\xml\\filename.xml";
```

It works.

I've created the installation file in Inno Setup. This works as well, copying my XML files exactly where I want them to go.

I open my application directly from the installation folder, from the Start menu icon, from a desktop shortcut, and it works fine.

I make some changes to my program, then I close it and start it again. Everything is fine: all the saved changes are read back from the XML.

But then I open the specified XML file and there are no changes!

I wouldn't bother as at least it's working, but:

1. When I uninstall the application then install it again to the same directory, changes made to the previously installed file are still there!
2. I'm *very* curious to know what's happening.

This only happens if the program is installed to *Program Files*. If I install it to *My Documents*, changes are shown in the XML files and after reinstalling it the default settings are restored as expected.

My questions are:

1. Where are those XML files being stored, and how can I load it if the specified path points to *Program Files* and they are not there?
2. Obviously, how do I fix it?

**EDIT**
Finally found those files in C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files[APPNAME]

Comment: what windows version are you using/having problems with?

Comment: with windows vista and newer, they really hardened the program files directory. i would advise against writing there.

Comment: So what is the best practice? Where to keep files for program so it would work for Windows Vista and newer and to easy access them by code?

Comment: try storing in local applicationd ata.

Comment: also when data are saved in local application data folder, the issue with uninstalling/installing application and user data not being cleaned will probably continue, installers usually by default don't remove user data during uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Check what is saved into your local application data folder (it's \Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\ for Windows 7).

It looks as if your app didn't have rights to save things in your ProgramFiles folder and saved it where it could, probably in this location:

```
String appData = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Also you may try running your application as administrator and check if changes to your xml data still doesn't show.

Comment: Yup, indeed. As I run it as Administrator it works fine.

It is not saved to any (common or user) AppData folder, I'm still searching...

Comment: it may change name to some random text, maybe search by expected content?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you print out the value of

```
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

then you should be able to see where your xml files are stored, if it is a console application just use Console to print if it is WPF print it to a label or something

Comment: I've tried that, but it prints out the proper value, "C://Program Files/MyProgramFolder/xml/filename.xml"